# "Premise" as a location

Tags: meaning

Can the word "premise" ever refer to a location or building?  I have noticed that "premise" is being used in the computer industry to refer to a computer system that is located at a customer's place of business.  I think that this is a misuse of the word and that the word "premises" should be used instead.

Comment: "on-premise" seems to be an alternative to "on-premises" to describe software installed on a customer's computer, as opposed to software accessed remotely.

Comment: @deadrat The OED says it’s always *premises* in the plural today.

Comment: And King Canute commanded the tide not to come in.  http://www.brianmadden.com/blogs/brianmadden/archive/2014/05/01/so-apparently-we-lost-the-grammar-war-and-on-premises-is-just-called-quot-on-premise-quot-now.aspx

Comment: The client insists the server be installed on their premises based on two premises: that they can provide better security and they need physical access to the machine.

Comment: As far as I know, it should always be "premises" (i.e. in the plural form).

Comment: I noticed this usage cropping up in U.S. computer-related writing about five years ago—and it is getting more prevalent, not less, as time goes on. I struggled against it at the computer magazines where I worked, but a lot of writers see no problem with _on-premise_ as an alternate form of _on-premises_. I think it's likely to achieve general acceptance within the next decade if the current trend continues. Sorry to be the bearer of an unpleasant prognosis, but real-world language choices don't always follow the path we might prefer.

Comment: Is that how we are to do this now?  Someone makes a grammar or spelling mistake, but they have enough clout that other people think it is correct and repeat it, and suddenly a word has a whole new meaning?  I refuse.  I have no authority to enforce it, but I will click my tongue, and perhaps roll my eyes, and certainly think less of anyone who does this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're right. If I'm understanding you, the uses you noticed were adjectival, for example, "the premise system started a major fire in the customer's clean room".

In a cursory search (online and the OED), I did not find a precedent for adjectival use of "premises" in the singular, much less use in the singular as a noun to describe a "location or building".

It is of course not the first time, nor will it be the last, that the computer industry has so callowly abused our fine English language.

Answer (score 2):

The use of "premise" as a nominal adjective (particularly in the computer-related instances you are citing) is based on the need to differentiate between computer and resource locations which are external.  While the actual use of the word may not be accurate in the modern understanding of "premise" (or as it is more normally used, "premises", as in relating to the premises of a deed), co-opting words for clarity is quite common in business parlance.

In short, if the computer industry is on board with the use of the phrase, it will quite shortly become linguistic law.  Premise can and does refer to locations (albeit normally in plural form), and its use here is due to a lack of a ready alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The computer industry is not the sole malefactor misusing these two words. I've heard it uttered maladroitly by electrical and building contractors; IT and IT technology installers; LEOs; security (alarm) firms; and the maintenance and operations staff at my school.

Definition of [premises](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/premises) in English:

From:

```
 http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/premises
```

> *plural noun*
>
> A house or building, together with its land and outbuildings, occupied by a business or considered in an official context:
>
> - business premises
> - supplying alcoholic liquor for consumption on the
>     premises

Definition of [premise](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/premise) in English:

From:

```
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/premise
```

> *noun*
>
> Logic
>
> 1 A previous statement or proposition from which another is inferred or follows as a conclusion:
>
> *if the premise is true, then the conclusion must be true*
>
> 1.1 An assertion or proposition which forms the basis for a work or theory:
>
> *the fundamental premise of the report*

And so on for verbs & whatnot.

Comment: Please add the source of the quote in plain text (just in case the link goes missing) and indicate quotations with `>`. Thanks. [It's explained in the Help on Answering, which I can't easily link to via the app.]

Answer (score 1):

Premises plural came to refer to a location because its legal sense of preamble or prologue refers to the introductory paragraphs, or premises, of a deed in which the property deeded (or transferred) by the document is defined and described by its boundaries, landmarks, survey points, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a real estate refers only to the soil, since the buildings are attached to it as legal and common sense consequence. However premises are used to describe both the land and buildings as a single entity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premises